# How to merge nested array to an array with a dimension larger using numpy?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have an array with the shape of (15) called `myArray`

Every instance of `myArray` is another array with a shape of (-1,10,15)

How can I expand the dimension of `myArray` instead of having nested arrays to obtain a single 4D array with the shape of (15,-1,10,15).

Comment: `np.stack(myArray)` might work

Comment: oh, it was very simple, Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can answer this so I can close this question? 
Maybe others might run into simple problems also :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array is 1d with object dtype, containing nd arrays

```
np.stack(arr)
```

will combine all the element arrays into one (n+1)d array - provided they all have the same shape.